# How do I play DVDs on Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, dvd

I recently updated to Windows 10 from Windows 7.

When I inserted a DVD into my Windows 7, it would start playing right away! But now I'm on Windows 10 and when I put the disk in nothing happens. When I open it in my computer I just see a folder full of weirdly-named files.

How do I watch a DVD on my Windows 10?

Thank you,
Kit

she/her/hers

Comment: Installing VLC is probably the easiest solution.

Comment: https://www.pcmag.com/news/355889/how-to-play-dvds-in-windows-10

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible solutions, either by installing VLC or Microsoft's official app, Windows DVD Player.

### Option 1: VLC

I recommend this option because it is free and easy, and has always worked for me. Go to the [VideoLan download website](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html), select the version that you need and install it like any other program. Then all you have to do is insert the DVD, go to *Media* then the *Browse* button on the dialog box and select where the DVD is mounted in your file system. The video should begin to play once you click the *Play* button.

### Option 2: Windows DVD Player

This is what Microsoft recommends to play DVDs because it integrates with their operating system, but it also costs $15. You can install it from the Windows Store by searching for it in the search box or by clicking [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/p/windows-dvd-player/9nblggh2j19w). After it installs all you have to do is insert the DVD and it should start playback automatically.